# Hadoop MapFile: how to transfer the writable value to its original class?

Tags: hadoop, nutch

There is nutch data in Hadoop, and I get the value by the method get(key,val), but how can I transfer the writable data to its original class. My code is paste bellow:

```
Text key = new Text();
key.set(url);
Writable value = null;
value = reader.get(key, value);
```

the value is like this:

```
Version: -1
url:http://www.google.com
base: http://www.google.com
contentType: application/xhtml+xml
metadata:***
Content:
<!DOCTYPE html****
```

And how can I get the get the Content only or contentType?
Can I transfer the value to its original class and use getContent() method?

Comment: What's the runtime type/class of `value`? Does this concrete class have methods to extract the fields you're interested in?

Comment: no such method, just getclass(), tostring(),notify(),readfields()

Comment: I'll ask again, what's the **runtime** type of the `value` - Writable is the **compile** time type and the methods you've listed are for that interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the runtime type of `value` is [`org.apache.nutch.protocol.Content`](http://nutch.apache.org/apidocs-1.4/org/apache/nutch/protocol/Content.html) then yes, you can cast to that type and then call the `getContent()` method

```
Content content = (Content) value;
content.getContent();
```